# Very slow query generated getting meta data from posts

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I need to process some meta_query fields.

```
$meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                [
                    'key'       => '_sale_price',
                    'value'     => $price_range,
                    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
                ],
                [
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    [
                        'key'     => '_regular_price',
                        'value'   => $price_range,
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                    ],
                    [
                        'key'     => '_sale_price',
                        'value'   => '1',
                        'compare' => '<',
                    ]
                ]
            );
$query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
```

This produces an SQL query with many INNER JOINS and it is very slow!

Full query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2
ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup
ON wp_posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
SELECT object_id
FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (10,423) ) )
AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '100'
AND '199' )
OR ( ( mt1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '100'
AND '199' )
AND ( mt2.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND mt2.meta_value < '1' ) ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wc_product_meta_lookup.max_price DESC, wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 24
```

Same result can be achieved using simple WHERE statements and avoid expensive joins.
How can I get Wordpress to generate more efficient SQL in this case?

Thanks,
Rudolf

Comment: Now that you have the literal SQL query, you could use `wp_db` to first run the select with the complicated `where` part, then loop through the results to lookup the `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` and `wp_postmeta` things.

Comment: Also, it appears that `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` can slow down things.